# Views Question - Related Taxonomy Terms

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I'm a Drupal noob, so this may be a simple question. I have two taxonomies created, one called Programs and another called Divisions. There is a "Division" field in the "Program" taxonomy. For example:

**Programs**

- Math
- English
- Art
- Communication
- Biology

**Divisions**

- Humanities
- Science

Art, English, and Communication are all related to Humanities
Math and Biology are related to Science

I have used Views to build a page that will display information for each program. URL format is academics/programs/biology, academics/programs/art, etc.

I'm trying to create a Views pane that will display related programs, but I'm having some difficulty. Essentially, I want it to a display a list of programs that have the same Division. How would I go about accomplishing this since the URL does not have the Division term in it, but rather the Program term?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you put the hierarchical structure into the path you could use a contextual filter to show the related programs in a view. The path would look like: programs/humanities/English

The contextual filter would look at the taxonomy term in position 2 and show related programs (other humanities programs in this example)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using taxonomy term as the field in programs rather use entity reference with taxonomy term and bundle divisions.

I also installed [Views arguments in filters](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/itangalo/1086472) in order to get rid of listing the program in the second view. You can omit this if it is not a requirement.

Then set up your second view as follows (note I just used an attachment but you can alter as you like):

**View**: showing taxonomy terms filtered by Programs

**Contextual filter**: global null, default value = Taxonomy term ID from URL, Validator = Taxonomy term of Vocabulary Programs and Field filter type = Term name

**Relationships:**

**Relationship 1**: A bridge to the Taxonomy term entity that is referenced via field_division

**Relationship 2**: A bridge to the Taxonomy term entity that is referencing Taxonomy term via field_division, ans set its relationship to relationship 1

**Fields**:

Taxonomy term fields with the relationship set to relationship 2

**Filter criteria:**

**Taxonomy vocabulary:** machine name = Programs

**Term Name:** set the value to =%1 (picked up from global null via views arguments in filters

**Term Name:** set the value to !=%1 and add relationship 2.